# Are results after performing operations on AVL trees ambiguous?

Tags: trees

After performing operations (e.g. insertion/deletion of a node - rotations) on an AVL tree, is the result fully determined by the order of insertion on the initial tree, or do multiple solutions exists that satisfy all AVL properties?

Comment: When you say "operation", do you include only the type of operation (e.g., insert vs delete), or also the specific value that was inserted/deleted?

Answer (score 1):

In standard way the order of operations determines the tree shape - there are no ambiguous choices during insertion / deletion or rebalancing so it is unique.

There are more possible trees if you consider some additional operations that do not violate AVL properties like introducing stricter balance or rotating -1 to +1, please remember that this operations are non-standard and changing -1 to +1 serves only one purpose - to show different existing trees with AVL properties.